# Django Form Update Failing with a NULL not allowed

Tags: django, forms, django-forms

I have a customer instance that I am trying to update only a FEW fields in using a form, as the rest is 'behind the scenes' info.

I am receiving this error:
`Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'iddef_cst', table 'EasyTrade20.dbo.app_customer_cst'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails`

Even though that record was already populated and already has that value included.

views.py:

```
def edit_customer(request, id):
    customer_obj = get_object_or_404(AppCustomerCst, id_cst=id)
    form = CustomerMaintForm(request.POST, instance=customer_obj)
    if form.is_valid:
        form.save()
```

forms.py

```
class CustomerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = AppCustomerCst
        fields = ('id_cst', 'is_active_cst', 'name_cst', 'address_1_cst', 'address_2_cst', 'address_3_cst',
                  'city_cst', 'state_cst', 'zip_cst', 'country_cst', 'salesrep_cst', 'type_cst',
                  'is_allowed_flat_cst', 'balance_notify_cst', 'receive_emails_cst',
                  'contact_domain_cst'
```

I have tried to create an instance of the form with `form.save(commit=False)` and use the fields from `customer_obj` to pass the current values to the form for update, but it seems the final `form.save()` creates a new object.   Is there any clean way to use a `ModelForm` to update only a handful of fields in a model instance?

Comment: you are using CustomerMaintForm and CustomerForm , why?

Comment: You are right!  I originally created 2 forms, one for adding and one for maintaining.  I then realized that wasn't the best way, and missed updating this function.  Thanks!

Comment: is it solved...?

Comment: yes, I updated my view to be just CustomerForm() and that corrected the issue.

Comment: perfect .........